# how to check if someone override a directory?

Tags: linux, hashsum, checksum

Lets say i have an existing directory and someone did cp -r over this and some files changed. I want to detect this change. How can i do it ?

I thought of using md5 or some checksum calculator for directory but it could make my program slow since directory size can be way huge.

Comment: you can use a backup or rsync to compare in simulation mode of course it will be really faster that the md5 method

Comment: Please be more specific. Tell us what directory we're talking and if your goal is informative or tampering detection. Is it a personal or system directory? Debian holds e.g. package checksums at `/var/lib/dpkg/info/*.md5sums` (that can be edited by privileged users). For private data you may as well use `git`. Tampering detection is a whole other can of worms.